# Powersets, $\sigma$-algebras, and measures

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

It is my understanding that $\sigma$-algebras are necessary to satisfy certain desired properties of a measure, and that these conditions are mutually inconsistent if we consider arbitrary open sets of $\mathbb{R}$. However, I have also read that power set of a set is necessarily a $\sigma$-algebra, so how come we cannot use the power set of $\mathbb{R}$ to define a measure space? I feel I am missing something fundamental here.

Comment: $(\Bbb R,\mathcal P(\Bbb R))$ can be classified as a [measurable space](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Measurable_space). But this space cannot be equipped with every measure you like. If AC is accepted then the space cannot be equipped with a measure having the characteristics of the Lebesgue measure. It can however be equipped with e.g. the counting measure (sending a set to its cardinality if it is finite and to $\infty$ otherwise).

Comment: The power set of $\mathbb R$ is indeed the domain of some measures, but not of some other, especially important measures, like the Lebesgue measure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are disjoint subsets $A$ and $B$ of $\mathbb{R}$ such that
$$\mu(A\cup B)<\mu(A)+\mu(B)$$
violating the [additivity condition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Measure_(mathematics)) of a measure $\mu$ induced from the "length" function on intervals. The collection of (Lebesgue) measurable sets is strictly smaller than the powerset.

EDIT: It is pointed out in the comments that the powerset is an adequate sigma-algebra for other measures like "atomic" measures on $\mathbb{R}$. Thus your intuition is not far off.

Comment: That makes a lot more sense now, thanks!